# How can I open a port in Kubuntu 19.10?

Tags: command-line, networking, kubuntu, 19.10

My application works by accessing a port. In Ubuntu 18.10, it used to automatically assign to the specific port. Now I have upgraded to Kubuntu 19.10 and whichever port I am mentioning in the application.properties, I get the below message:

```
**************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8888 failed to start. 
The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's 
listening on port 8888, or configure this application to listen on another port.

----------------------------------------
```

I was trying to access port 8888.

I'm unable to access it in Kubuntu 19.10.

I tried using `netstat -lpn` command but unable to get any info regarding port 8888.

I am not aware of which all ports can be used for the specific application and there is no list available which provides information about the open ports that can be used.

I went through [the Iptables how to page of the Ubuntu help site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo), but I'm still unable to either access the port, open the port or check the status of the port.

[image: screenshot of the message]

Comment: your question isn't clear. it might be helpful if instead of providing a (paritial) photo of your commands, you will [edit] your question with the text of the commands you executed, what have you expect to get, and what you actually got

Comment: sure will do that.

Comment: There is nothing you have to configure by default to bind to port 8888. Maybe the Tomcat server already runs by default and hooks on to 8888. Maybe it needs root (`sudo`) now to bind to 8888. But yea, Kubuntu by itself does nothing to prevent you from running an application over 8888. And you don't even want to forward at this point, it fails to bind locally. There is no internet involved at this point yet.

Comment: I tried to kill the tomcat server thinking that it already hooks on to the 8888 but nothing seemed to be working. For that case, when i am changing the port to 1716 or 33606 (some random number) i get the same issue